# Upload image attachment with upload quickbook api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have been looking for solution from last-2 days, also this is my first question here so bear with me.

I am trying to upload jpg image with upload qbo api, but keep getting a error code 500 with message Unsupported OperationOperation Cannot consume content type is not supported.

My request is:

```
@client = Signet::OAuth1::Client.new(    
    :temporary_credential_uri => "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token",    
    :authorization_uri => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",    
    :token_credential_uri => "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token",    
    :client_credential_key => App.find_by_name('quickbooks').clientid,    
    :client_credential_secret => App.find_by_name('quickbooks').clientsecret    
   )    
   @client.token_credential_key = quickbooks.accesstoken    
   @client.token_credential_secret = quickbooks.refreshtoken    
   realmid =quickbooks.uid    
   url = Rails.env.eql?("development")? "sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com" : "quickbooks.api.intuit.com"

object = {
       "AttachableRef": [
       {
        "EntityRef": {
         "type": "Invoice",
         "value": "95"
        }
       }
      ],
       "FileName": params[:file].original_filename,
       "ContentType": "image/jpg"
      }
   original_request = [
     'Post',
     "https://#{url}/v3/company/#{realmid}/upload",
     [  
       ['Content-Type', 'application/json'],
       ['boundary', '0be01941e049'],
     ],
     [object.to_json]
   ]
   response = @client.fetch_protected_resource(:request => original_request)
```

In response got:

```
<Error code=\"500\"><Message>Unsupported Operation</Message><Detail>Operation Cannot consume content type is not supported.</Detail></Error></Fault></IntuitResponse>"
```

Any kinda help would be appreciated. Thanks

**:EDIT**

Using quickbook-ruby gem---- 'github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#uploading-an-actual-file'

```
::QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER = OAuth::Consumer.new(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, {
    :site                 => "https://oauth.intuit.com",
    :request_token_path   => "/oauth/v1/get_request_token",
    :authorize_url        => "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin",
    :access_token_path    => "/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
})
meta = Quickbooks::Model::Attachable.new
meta.file_name = "monkey.jpg"
meta.note = "A note"
meta.content_type = "image/jpg"
entity = Quickbooks::Model::BaseReference.new(123, type: 'Transfer')
meta.attachable_ref = Quickbooks::Model::AttachableRef.new(entity)
doc_path = 'Add file path'
 upload_service = Quickbooks::Service::Upload.new(:realm_id=> '123XXX', :access_token=> 'QTYXXXXX')
result = upload_service.upload(doc_path, "image/jpeg")
```

I am facing an error 
NoMethodError: undefined method `post_with_multipart' for "erXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6":String

Even though i'm not using any method named post_with_multipart in my code, This is something i'm getting in response when I try to upload image
**result = upload_service.upload(doc_path, "image/jpeg")**

Comment: How do you get `params[:file]` here?

Comment: Params[:file] is the image i'm trying to upload, I'm hitting my method with postman and from there i'm attaching the image

Comment: Well so far as i guessed you are getting params[:file], from front end using file field. so here by when you will check it, it will show you something like `actiondispatcher`, so basically its not the physical file that would be uploaded, you can say params[:file] is byte code or meta data, so i have to say that, before doing api call you would have to convert this byte code into physical file. probably you understand it, or let me know for further guidance.

Comment: check out this https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#uploading-an-actual-file
As its sending file meta data also with api, so you will have to pass `params[:file]` also.

Comment: I already tried that by saving image into system and uploading or also I put that image in public folder,I assume the json syntax i'm using in object and original;_request for sending image maybe isn't correct

Comment: i'm using in json format request, not using exact gem method. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/attachable

Comment: @Gabbar I am trying to use your link(quickbook-ruby gem) with this link github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby#uploading-an-actual-file , facing error NoMethodError: undefined method `post_with_multipart' for "XXXXXXXXX":String. Please help me out, what exactly this error.

Comment: Naina ... you need to post how you are calling or sending these requests for us to help.  Also ... if you are getting `NoMethodError`, you need to be in the rails console hacking out how to send that request.

Comment: I have edited code with using quickbook-ruby gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone lands here in search of solution, This is how I fixed it.
So what I was collectively doing wrong is I wasn't passing access token with OAuth.

```
token = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb, oauth_token, oauth_secret)
```